# How to share a zfs filesystem including it's child filesystems via nfs? Attempted approaches failed to share child filesystems

Tags: linux, nfs, zfs, zfsonlinux

How to share the whole zpool (including child filesystems) via nfs?

Using the belowzfs filesystems:

```
NAME               USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
backup             7.22T  6.83T  3.94T  /backup
backup/compressed  3.28T  6.83T  3.28T  /backup/compressed
```

When `backup` is shared directly using `nfs-kernel-server`, it's contents are available from nfs-clients. Unfortunately the 'compressed folder' (`backup/compressed`) shows up however it's contents does not.

If `backup/compressed` is shared using `sudo zfs set sharenfs=on backup/compressed` or `nfs-kernel-server`, the folder is still inaccessible.

I have confirmed that both filesystems have been shared:

```
showmount -e
Export list for node1:
/backup/compressed *
/backup            *
```

How to share the zfs filesystem and it's child filesystems using nfs?

**Update:**

`cat /proc/fs/nfsd/exports` returns:

```
# Version 1.1
# Path Client(Flags) # IPs
/   192.168.1.0/24(ro,root_squash,sync,no_wdelay,no_subtree_check,v4root,fsid=0,uuid=4093d757:04e84107:a4f18396:1f6546f3,sec=1)
/backup/compressed  192.168.1.0/24(rw,root_squash,all_squash,sync,wdelay,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,uuid=5beeba85:0006e861:00000000:00000000,sec=1)
/backup 192.168.1.0/24(ro,root_squash,sync,no_wdelay,no_subtree_check,v4root,uuid=093f132b:00211eeb:00000000:00000000,sec=1)
/backup/compressed  192.168.2.0/24(rw,root_squash,all_squash,sync,wdelay,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,uuid=5beeba85:0006e861:00000000:00000000,sec=1)
```

Comment: What is the content of `/proc/fs/nfsd/exportfs`? Add it to your question.

Comment: @Thomas I updated the post with the details of `/proc/fs/nfsd/exports`

Comment: According to that the `/backup/compressed` is exported as `read-write` and should be accessible. The `/backup` folder is `read-only`. What exactly do you mean by *not accessible*? Try to remount the NFS share on the client and try to mount the `/backup/compressed` folder directly with `mount -t nfs <your-server-ip>:/backup/compressed <mount-point>`.

Comment: Just repeating @Thomas really but have you actually mounted the compressed folder on the client? These are two separate filesystems so need sharing and mounting independently.